# How to design an algorithm that associates names with values in a list? Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

This is a smaller algorithm that is part of a larger assignment. I have two lists. One is a list of people and one is a list of lists of each person's  answer/s to different questions. Each question may have multiple answers or just one.

Here's an example of the lists. The first list is four names. Sam, Mary, Bob, Dan. The second list goes like this, Sam's answer to question 1, Mary's answer to question1, Bob's answer to question 1, Dan's answer to question 1, Sam's answer to question 2, Mary's answer to question 2, Bob's answer to question 2, Dan's answer to question 2.... How would I develop an algorithm to collect and group the answers with correct person from the name list? Ideally this algorithm would work for any number of people, and questions.

Here's a more literal example of each list.

```
list1 = ['Sam', 'Mary', 'Bob', 'Dan']
list2 = [['Red', 'Green'], 
         ['Blue', 'Yellow'], 
         ['Green', 'Red'], 
         ['Orange', 'Brown'], 
         [1, 4, 5],
         [3, 7, 8], 
         [9, 5, 4], 
         [3, 8, 2], 
         [A], [C], [D], [D]]
```

Comment: You can use dictionary instead of lists. Why are you insisting on list ?

Comment: `N = len(list1)` and then `list2[0::N]` to collect all items for the first person. Can you generalise it from here?

Comment: I don't insist on using a list to group the answers with the names. How would I do that using a dictionary?

Comment: @Reti43 How would I do it for the second person?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to collect answers from your current structure in a `dict`, you could do the following (building on @Reti43's comment):

```
n = len(list1)  # number of players
answer_dict = {list1[i]: list2[i::n] for i in xrange(n)}  # dict comprehension

# answer_dict
# {
#     'Sam':  [['Red', 'Green'], [1, 4, 5], [A]],
#     ...
# }
```

The slice operator `[start:end:step]` collects all elements of a list from `start` (inclusively, default: `0`) to `end` (exclusively, default: `len(list)`) in steps of `step` (default: `1`).

Now you would access Mary's answer to the 3rd question:

```
answer_dict['Mary'][2]
```

Comment: Ah, perfect answer. Saves me the effort. :) The only thing missing, for the sake of completion, is a demonstration of accessing the results, e.g., `answer_dict['Bob'][1]`.